# anuglar 5 material mat-sidenav animation not working on close

Tags: angular, animation, angular-material, angular5, sidenav

I'm having a weird animation problem with closing the material navbar (). The animation works fine when I'm opening the navbar, but when I close it the animation to close it does not seem to play. Instead, it just dispersal when the "animation time" is over. However, the closing-animation DOES work when one is opening the navbar, and before it completes, closes it. So fast toggling open and closing before the animation/transition is done makes it work like expected. It looks something like this:

[animation not working on close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geo00.gif)

It's supposed to work like this:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/perxaynqger?file=app%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.ts

**SEE BELOW FOR CODE**

**app.module.ts**

```
// ANGULAR MODULES
import { BrowserModule }           from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule }                from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }             from '@angular/forms'; // <-- NgModel lives here
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatSliderModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatTooltipModule,
  MatStepperModule,
}                                  from '@angular/material';
import {CdkTableModule}            from '@angular/cdk/table';

// COMPOENTS AND SERVICES
import { AppComponent }            from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule }        from './app-routing.module';
import { AboutMeComponent }        from './components/about-me/about-me.component';
import { HomeComponent }           from './components/home/home.component';
import { ProjectsComponent }       from './components/projects/projects.component';
import { WhyMeComponent }          from './components/why-me/why-me.component';

// MATERIAL MODULE

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    CdkTableModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AboutMeComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProjectsComponent,
    WhyMeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, NgModule, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectorRef }           from '@angular/core';
import { MatIcon, MatIconButtonCssMatStyler, MatIconBase, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';
import { AnimationEvent, trigger, state, style, group, }                  from '@angular/animations';
import { animate, transition, keyframes, stagger, query}                  from '@angular/animations';
import { MediaMatcher }                                                   from '@angular/cdk/layout';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})

export class AppComponent {

  mobileQuery: MediaQueryList;

  private _mobileQueryListener: () => void;

  constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, media: MediaMatcher) {
    this.mobileQuery = media.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');
    this._mobileQueryListener = () => changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
  }
}
```

**app.comonent.html**

```
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="example-toolbar">
    <button mat-icon-button class="menu-icon" (click)="snav.toggle()">
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <h1 class="app-name">Portfolio - v2</h1>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav #snav [mode]="'side'">
      <mat-nav-list>
        <!--<a mat-list-item routerLink="." *ngFor="let nav of fillerNav">{{nav}}</a>-->
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="/home">Home</a>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="/about-me">About me</a>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="/projects">Projects</a>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <main> 
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </main>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```